# Set View LandscapeLeft (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uiwebview, rotation

Hey guys,
just starting off with the iPhone SDK, I've built a simple iPhone app that displays locally stored webpages, but I want to get the app to start with the UIWebView sideways (Landscape left).

I've set `Initial interface orientation` to `Landscape (left home button)` in the plist, but how do I actually rotate the view, because when I load it up, the view stays in portrait and the device is sideways!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you wanna allow all orientations if user move his iPhone
just add this in your UIViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return YES
}
```